# Liferay 7.3.2: Aria-expanded stuck on true after changing a page

Tags: sass, freemarker, liferay-7, liferay-7.3

I have few dropdowns on my page, with buttons opening and closing a dropdown. Everything goes well after initial page load, but **after changing to a different page**, the dropdown opens with a click, but never closes. It seems that button's `aria-expanded` is stuck on `true` and the dropped down `div` has classes `collapse open`, which tries to collapse but won't ever do it (clicking the button gives the div `collapsing` class and then returns).

I have no idea why this happens and and if it's got to do with Liferay, freemarker, css or any of those...

This is my application display template:

```html
<div id="a_language_selector">
    <button
        aria-controls="a_language_list"
        aria-expanded="false"
        role="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#a_language_list"
    >
        <!-- CHANGE THIS -->
        <@liferay.language key="EN" />
    </button>

    <ul
        id="a_language_list"
        class="panel-collapse collapse"
        aria-labelledby="a_language_list"
    >
        <#if entries?has_content>
            <#list entries as navigationEntry>
                <li aria-label="${navigationEntry.getName()}">
                    <a href="${navigationEntry.getURL()}">
                        ${navigationEntry.getName()}
                    </a>
                </li>
            </#list>
        </#if>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was found and has to do with Liferay's own javascript (SennaJS)!

Changing a page in Liferay doesn't update the whole site and leaves old information lying around the session, breaking the collapsing.

I added this line to my `portal-ext.properties` and while it now loads after all page changes, it works well!

```
javascript.single.page.application.enabled=false
```

More information found [here](https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017880672-Automatic-Single-Page-Applications) (help.liferay.com)